# Make enemies attack surface of building, not center

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game, a player must defend a building from attacking enemies. The ground enemies spawn at random places around the building, and they all walk towards the building to start attacking it with their axes:

```
agent.SetDestination(target.position);
```

`target.position` is the position of the building object.

It makes sense of course that the enemies try to reach the center of the building, but they should attack the surface. I tried adding

```
if (distance <= attackDistance)
```

to make sure the enemies respect a minimum distance, but since the building is not a sphere this doesn't work very good.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: You could raycast against the building's collider and when the distance between the Unit and the `RaycastHit.point` is below the `attackDistance`, then attack.

Answer (score 0):

You can put empty gameObjects around the building as little "attack points"

But a more proper way to do this is to make it so when enemies detect a collision with the walls, they go into an attacking state.

Other than that, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Are they attacking a compound around the building? Are they just bashing an axe on the walls of a building?

I could help you further if you gave more information.